# Запятая после "если"

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый вечер! Подскажите, стоит ли ставить запятую после "если"?

Если, вместо того чтобы предаваться воспоминаниям, вы сделаете... , это поможет... .

Answer (score 2):

Постановку запятой после "если" можно обосновать двумя правилами. Во-первых, на стыке двух союзов (ЕСЛИ и ВМЕСТО ТОГО ЧТОБЫ) запятая ставится, так как отсутствует вторая часть двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО. Во-вторых, Розенталь допускает обособление в этом предложении дополнения ВМЕСТО ТОГО ЧТОБЫ ПРЕДАВАТЬСЯ ВОСПОМИНАНИЯМ.

Answer (score 2):

Если, вместо того чтобы предаваться воспоминаниям, вы сделаете... , это поможет...
Мне кажется, это СПП с двумя видами придаточных.
Главное  - это поможет..., вопрос: поможет - при каком условии?  - первое придаточное - если вы сделаете..., вопрос: сделаете - вместо чего? - вместо того чтобы предаваться воспоминаниям - второе придаточное.
Таким образом, получается, что одно придаточное стоит внутри другого и должно выделяться запятыми с двух сторон.

Answer (score 0):

На мой непросвещенный взгляд: "Если вместо того, чтобы предаваться воспоминаниям, вы сделаете нечто, это (нечто) вам поможет".

Ибо 1 Это (нечто) вам поможет. 2 (Если) вместо того вы сделаете это (нечто). 3 (Чтобы) предаваться воспоминаниям.